# Running simple cron on MAMP

Tags: cron, mamp

How can I get http://localhost:8888/site_name/index.php to run every 30 min until I manually stop it (edit the cron file)? This is on a Mac running MAMP.

I know how to set one up using the wizard in a cpanel but have never done this on MAMP before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a guide to using cron on OSX : http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=2001020700163714

in cron (`crontab -e` in a terminal) enter :

0,30    *    *    *    *    root    curl http://localhost:8888/site_name/index.php > /dev/null